# "import" string in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

It's been a while since I touched Android Studio.  I thought I recalled a feature where I could type some code, for example like

```
public String UserName;
```

And I thought there was a way to click on the text "string" in the editor and maybe right click or a lightbulb would pop up that streamlined the process of generating the necessary code up above the class, something like,

```
import java.lang.String;
```

but I can't figure it out any more.  Am I thinking of some other IDE?

Comment: Autoimport? Alt+Enter also makes the dialog pop up.

Comment: Alt + Enter? IntelliJ has this. Not sure about astudio.

Comment: String cannot be imported. If that is what you're trying it on.

Comment: @LppEdd doh!  I had a lower-case 's', I had public string UserName; in my code

Comment: @KyleSweet well that happen if you're not really used to work with Java! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually String does not have to be imported... It is a built-in data type and it is always available without an import.

String is part of the Java.lang packages (`Java.lang.String`) and is auto-imported.

This is also the reason why you cannot import it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Alt + Enter
```

You can also go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Auto Import and change "Insert imports on paste" value to all and add ambigous imports on the fly if you don't wanna have to press the buttons.

Comment: Thanks!  I have every option possible enabled there.